# how to query api with path and query?

Tags: rest, retrofit, retrofit2

Base url: `http://some-url.com/ws-v2/mobile/android/`

Hello,
I try to call this api and I unknown exception. something is wrong with my interface.

Full url: `http://some-url.com/ws-v2/mobile/android/genre/tvshows?id=723&page=1&limit=25&sort=newest`

-after "genre" I pass the genre type
-Pass id Query 
-page, lime, sort (type)

Retrofit interface:

```
@GET("genre/{type}") Call<GenreResponse> getGenres(
      @Path("type") String genreType,
      @Query("id") String id,
      @Query("page") int page,
      @Query("limit") int limit,
      @Query("sort") String sortType);
```

How to get this work?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide stacktrace, GenreResponse class and JSON example from API documentation?

Comment: <-- END HTTP (3526-byte body)
11-09 17:01:52.070 6659-7897/com.mintmark.WallaVOD D/OkHttp: --> GET http://ws.vod.walla.co.il/ws-v2/mobile/android/genre/series?id=7623&page=1&limit=25&sort=newest http/1.1
11-09 17:01:52.070 6659-7897/com.mintmark.WallaVOD D/OkHttp: --> END GET
I want to get: http://ws.vod.walla.co.il/ws-v2/mobile/android/genre/movies?id=7623&page=1&limit=25&sort=newest

Comment: It's pretty obvious that there is no such page: http://ws.vod.walla.co.il/ws-v2/mobile/android/genre/series
You should ask API provider about it.